# Can I award bounty to my self?

Tags: support

Can I award bounty to my self after self answering the featured question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can not award bounty to your own answer.

Documented at the [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> **How is a bounty awarded?**
>
> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. **(You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)**

For the detailed information, visit the FAQ: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/260388):

> **Can I award a bounty to my own answer?**
>
> No. This used to be possible, but [it has been disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97802). The user would not get the reputation back, and the bounty will be displayed as +0, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation

Comment: If I answer and accept my answer, will the system award to me after 24 hrs of bounty expiry.

Comment: @MohMur You will not get bounty. You can only award to other answers.